# Possible to use geometry node on a selection of vertices on a model?

Tags: geometry-nodes

Is it possible to apply a geometry node to a selection of vertices on a model?

Basically I have a model where in certain areas I want to increase the subdivision count to get more details from a displacement modifier, but I don't want to increase the subdivision count for the entire thing.

I have an alternate workflow where I can apply the subdivision surface node to individual pieces, then join the separate geometries later. But if possible I'd like to avoid complicating the final assembly of model parts. This ultimately is all manifold and ready for 3d printing.

Comment: you can't subdivide just part of the mesh with geometry nodes, I mean, you can easily select and separate some geometry, subdivide it and join again, but you will get non manifold edges...

Comment: @alambre yeah that's what I was thinking was going to happen.

Comment: depending on the mesh you could try to fix this inside nodes, picking the edge, merging every 2 or 4 verts and then joining with the rest of geometry... not easy but could work for some topologies I think

Comment: A different (also not very elegant) way of doing it would be if you select the faces which should have a higher resolution, then subdivide them in _Edit Mode_. This way the selection has a higher basic resolution, so the _Subdivision Surface_ increases this even more.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, this is how I would do it... this way there's even a slight transition from lower resolution to higher resolution:

- Select a part of the mesh which should be subdivided more than the rest, right-click and choose *Subdivide*.

[image: first subdivide]

- Then I select a little less by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Num -</kbd> and subdivide it again.

[image: second subdivide]

- And then I do that once again so the end result looks like this:

[image: subdivision result]

- Now I add a *Subdivision Surface* modifier to increase the resolution even more and add a *Displacement* modifier afterwards, so the object has areas of differently high detailed displacement.

[image: displacement]